# Export Ubuntu 13 VMWare Home folder to be use on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mount, ubuntu-13.04

I run Ubuntu 13 on VMWare Fusion on Mac OS X.  I prefer to do my development on the Mac since the Mac keyboard and shortcuts on Ubuntu are either difficult to setup, or sometimes don't work.

One solution I used before was to export the /home folder on Ubuntu via NFS and mount it on OS X.  However, this caused problems because in order to be able to write to files, I had to change the GUID of the Mac user to match that of Ubuntu and that caused all kinds of problems on the Mac (Google Drive stopped working, etc).

Now I have a new project and a few hours this afternoon, and I'd like to setup this environment correctly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using VMware Fusion's "Shared Folders" option: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1004055